# Use Jquery to set an element closed by default

Tags: jquery, css

I have some Jquery that adds a collapse event when you click an icon to slide up and down some content as below:

```
$("[data-widget='collapse']").click(function() {
    //Find the box parent        
    var box = $(this).parents(".box").first();
    //Find the body and the footer
    var bf = box.find(".box-body, .box-footer");
    if (!box.hasClass("collapsed-box")) {
        box.addClass("collapsed-box");
        //Convert minus into plus
        $(this).children(".fa-minus").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        bf.slideUp();
    } else {
        box.removeClass("collapsed-box");
        //Convert plus into minus
        $(this).children(".fa-plus").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        bf.slideDown();
    }
});
```

But What I would also like to do is add the same .collapsed-box class to some elements but default so they start collapsed/closed, but that the open and close event still works after.

Would I need to edit the above and or add another function?

Thanks

Comment: just add the class `.collapsed-box` in the html of the elements closed by default (or add it with jquery like `$('.collapsed-default').addClass('collapsed-box')`) on page init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I thought you could just trigger the click event on all the elements, but you probably don't want to see the animation (i.e., the sliding) when the page loads. Therefore, you would have to add some code for this. I think the following would do:

```
var $collapsables = $("[data-widget='collapse']");

$collapsables.each(function() {
    var $collapsable = $(this),
        $box = $collapsable.closest(".box");
    if ($box.hasClass("collapsed-box")) {
        $collapsable.children(".fa-minus").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        $box.find(".box-body, .box-footer").hide();
    }
});
```

Note: The code above uses `.closest(".box")`, rather than `.parents(".box").first()`.